# Understanding geolocation example

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, google-api

I am looking at a geolocation example which gives a user directions to Alexanderplatz, Berlin from their geolocation but I'm having trouble understanding the two separate fallbacks:

```
        function () {
                // Gelocation fallback: Defaults to Stockholm, Sweden
                createMap({
                    coords : false,
                    address : "Sveavägen, Stockholm"
                });
            }
        );
    }
    else {
        // No geolocation fallback: Defaults to Lisbon, Portugal
        createMap({
            coords : false,
            address : "Lisbon, Portugal"
        });
```

Here is the full code:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.se/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
    (function () {
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService(),
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(),
            createMap = function (start) {
                var travel = {
                        origin : (start.coords)? new google.maps.LatLng(start.lat, start.lng) : start.address,
                        destination : "Alexanderplatz, Berlin",
                        travelMode : google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                        // Exchanging DRIVING to WALKING above can prove quite amusing :-)
                    },
                    mapOptions = {
                        zoom: 10,
                        // Default view: downtown Stockholm
                        center : new google.maps.LatLng(59.3325215, 18.0643818),
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
                directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
                directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("map-directions"));
                directionsService.route(travel, function(result, status) {
                    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
                    }
                });
            };

            // Check for geolocation support    
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                        // Success!
                        createMap({
                            coords : true,
                            lat : position.coords.latitude,
                            lng : position.coords.longitude
                        });
                    }, 
                    function () {
                        // Gelocation fallback: Defaults to Stockholm, Sweden
                        createMap({
                            coords : false,
                            address : "Sveavägen, Stockholm"
                        });
                    }
                );
            }
            else {
                // No geolocation fallback: Defaults to Lisbon, Portugal
                createMap({
                    coords : false,
                    address : "Lisbon, Portugal"
                });
            }
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: I am just looking someone to explain why there are two fallback options in the first line of code?

Comment: I didn't accept that answer as it did not help with my problem. I do accept all answers that help with my problem as you can see from my profile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code will check for [Geolocation](http://html5demos.com/geo) support of the browser at first:

```
// Check for geolocation support    
if (navigator.geolocation) {
```

If the browser doesn't support that new API, the `else` branch will set the maps' address to *Lisbon, Portugal*:

```
// else branch of geolocation check
else {
  // No geolocation fallback: Defaults to Lisbon, Portugal
  createMap({
    coords : false,
    address : "Lisbon, Portugal"
  });
}
```

**But** if the browser does offer the Geolocation API, the code will try to get the current position.
There are possibilities where the retreival fails, for example if the user doesn't allow using his location.
Then the maps' address will be set to *Sveavägen, Stockholm*.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  function (position) {
    // This is the success function: location stored in position!
  },

  function () {
    // This is the 'fail' function: location could not be retreived!
  }
);
```